# Remote procedure vs. Proxy tables

Tags: sybase

I'm a student and i'm doing my own database. But i have some questions that i can't answer yet. So, here is my question:

What is better to use in terms of efficiency and security, Proxy tables or Remote procedures?

Comment: There are many variables that affect efficiency and security. You will need to provide more information if you want a useful reply.